# How to highlight the last value of a time series on a y-axis

Tags: chart.js

As you can see on a screenshot below, the last value of the series is set and highlighted on the **Y** axis:

[image: sample]

I am looking for ways to reproduce this functionality with chartjs, any advice is appreciated in advance!